# How to import table data from excel into Azure FROM LINUX

Tags: linux, sql, microsoft-excel, azure

I'm in a database management class and the professor strictly teaches toward windows machines, so she uses Microsoft SQL Management Studio to interface with our databases. I have a linux machine, so I use Azure to interface with our databases. Azure is basically a watered down version of Management Studio. I have all of the functionality that I need, except I cannot import table data from an excel file into my databases through Azure.

The server that we use is a Microsoft SQL server. The server type listed on Management Studio is "Database Engine" (not sure if that helps). Is there any other type of database management utility that I can use in linux that gives me all of the functionality of Microsoft SQL Management Studio?

So, my specific question:
How can I import excel table data to my server from Azure on linux? If there is no way to do this, is there another good SQL Server Manager on linux that I can use?

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the DBMS independent JDBC based tools. As they are based on Java they run on any platform that supports Java including Linux.

And to my knowledge all of them support exporting data to Excel file.

All of them are free, DBeaver and DbVisualizer have a commercial version as well.

- [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) (Free and commercial version)
- [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) (Free and commercial version)
- [SQuirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) (Free and open source)
- [SQL Workbench/J](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/) (Free and open source)

Comment: Mind to include how one of those tools would solve the issue? If you check with our [answer quality discussion](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) you will find that just throwing in a bunch of names doesn't make an answer. Does any of them directly transfer Excel tables into a MSQL database? Do they all run on Linux? Do they have a price tag? How do they fit the OP's needs? What makes them recommendable? Please **[edit]** your post accordingly to make it an answer.